# How to solve "unknown key type ed25519" in CPanel Terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel, ssh-keygen

I'm following [this documentation from C Panel](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4404218477207-How-to-Configure-SSH-Key-Authentication-for-Use-with-cPanel-Git-Version-Control?utm_source=zendesk&utm_medium=deflarticles&utm_campaign=interdefllink) so that I can use Git version control with C Panel but I immediately hit a stumbling block.  When I add this line to the C Panel Terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "youremailaddress@domain.tld DAY-MONTH-YEAR" -f ~/.ssh/my_key
```

I get back:

```
unknown key type ed25519
```

Is there another way or do I need to install something via the Terminal?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember for the life of me...

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists or if anyone else encounters same blocker, you may attempt this solution.

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "youremailaddress@domain.tld" -f ~/.ssh/my_key
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).